# Complex mask draws corrupted shapes

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I assign a mask to a simple MovieClip with a square Bitmap in it. The mask is fairly complex shape drawn by an artist. The resulting masked bitmap looks correct inside Flash CS5, but when I run the SWF in Flash Player 10.2, the mask is corrupted. Let me try and describe it:

The shape itself is mostly visible, but certain scan lines (horizontal lines) of the resulting image "leak" to the right of the mask shape, all the way to the right border of the square bitmap. Some lines are also missing.
Here's an image:

[image]

The shape on the left is the mask used for the cracked bitmap, which you can see on the right, masked, with flaws.

Are there some limitations that we should be aware of when using masks? Does flash only handle simple shapes for masking?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up just creating a Pixel Bender shader filter to do it instead, because then you can just copy the alpha from the source pixel to the destination pixel, and blend another texture into the source image however you see fit. Performance is not bad, as you can cache it all as a bitmap.

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried to set both the mask and masked content to be cached as bitmaps?

Latest versions of Flash CS5 use Flash Player in design time to show its own content, so if it shows the mask as it should be, something must be happening behind the curtain.

Comment: Setting both objects cacheAsBitmap=true fixes the problem!  Thanks!
I'm using Flash CS5, not CS5.5.

Comment: Well, Flash CS5 also uses Flash Player to display the content in design time. Also, when using cacheAsBitmap you should be aware of its drawbacks, for example, if you rotate, scale, or animate the content of the object it will make Flash to consume a lot of CPU and memory.

Comment: Thanks, I'm aware of the issues with cacheAsBitmap. The masked object is a component of a larger MovieClip that we're doing our own bitmap caching on, so performance isn't a huge issue.

It's weird, though, that even when I use this object as a mask in a FLA with no ActionScript in it, the mask looks fine in CS5, but as soon as I test the SWF, the mask renders corrupted. So if what you say about CS5 using FP at design time is true, then maybe it's using a version of FP that does not have the bug that's in FP 10.2